# Multiple HashCodes for Java Objects

Tags: java, group-by, hashmap, hashcode

I'm trying to optimize some code, and when I do this I usually end up getting that helping hand from Hash structures.

What I want to do is divide objects into multiples sets based on some attributes in a very fast way. Basically like SQL GROUP BY statement but for Java.

The thing is that I want to use `HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object>>` to do this. I want to use multiple grouping ways but an `Object` can only have one `hashCode()`.

Is there a way to have multiple `hashCodes()` in order to be able to group by multiple methods? Are there other structures made to solve this kind of issues? Can I use Java 8 lambda expressions to send a `hashCode()` in the `HashMap` parameters? Am I silly and there is a super fast way that isn't this complicated?

Note: The hashCodes I want use multiple attributes that are not constant. So for example, creating a String that represents those attributes uniquely won't work because I'd have to refresh the string every time.

Comment: I don't understand. Let's say that object A is assigned to group 12 based on its current attributes. You store it in the HashMap. Then the attributes change: that will change the group of the object. So what you stored in the HashMap is now useless. A Map key should be immutable.

Comment: You shouldn't care about the value of the hash code.  You would have one `MultiMap` per group-by key set, with the `MultiMap` key being an object describing the group-by key and the value being the list of objects in that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like a rather convoluted pattern, and possibly a [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). You might have better luck asking a question about how to efficiently replicate `GROUP BY`-style queries in Java.

That said the easiest way to have multiple hash codes is to have multiple classes. Here's a trivial example:

```
public class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  /** the "real" hashCode() */
  public int hashCode() {
    return firstName.hashCode() + 1234 * lastName.hashCode();
  }
}

public class PersonWrapper1 {
  Person person;

  public int hashCode() {
    return person.firstName.hashCode();
  }
}

public class PersonWrapper2 {
  Person person;

  public int hashCode() {
    return person.lastName.hashCode();
  }
}
```

By using wrapper classes you can redefine the notion of equality in a type-safe way. Just be careful about how exactly you let these types interact; you can only compare instances of `Person`, `PersonWrapper1`, or `PersonWrapper2` with other instances of the same type; each class' `.equals()` method should return `false` if a different type is passed in.

---

You might also look at the [hashing utilities in Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained), they provide several different hashing functions, along with a [`BloomFilter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html) implementation, which is a data structure that relies on being able to use multiple hashing functions.

This is done by abstracting the hashing function into a `Funnel` class. `Funnel`-able classes simply pipe the values they use for equality into the `Funnel`, and callers (like `BloomFilter`) then actually compute the hash codes.

---

Your last paragraph is confusing; you cannot hope to store objects in a hash-based data structure and *then* change the values used to compute the hash code. If you do so, the object will no longer be discoverable in the data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the first two points. The last one doesn't apply to my code because after the values change, I'll just use another HashMap. I know it sounds weird but it is part of the strategy, HashMaps are meant to partition only once.

Comment: I also found the way to do the Group By with Java 8. Just had too google it, but I won't remove this question because I think you gave a very valid answer for non-java8 users.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a collection of objects and you want to produce different groupings analogous to SQL GROUP BY.  Each group-by is defined by a set of common values.  Create a group-by-key class for each distinct grouping type, each with an appropriate `hashCode()` and `equals()` method (as required by the `Map` contract).

For the following pseudocode I assume the existence of a `MultiMap` class that encapsulates the management of your map's `List<Object>` values. You could use Guava's `MultiMap` implementation.

```
// One group key
public class GroupKey1 {
    ...
    public GroupKey1(MyObject o) {
        // populate key from object
    }
    public GroupKey1(...) {
        // populate from individual values so we can create lookup keys
    }
    public int hashCode() { ... }
    public boolean equals() { ... }
}

// A second, different group key
public class GroupKey2 {
    ...
    public GroupKey2(MyObject o) {
        // populate key from object
    }
    public GroupKey2(...) {
        // populate from individual values so we can create lookup keys
    }
    ...
}
...
MultiMap<GroupKey1,MyObject> group1 = new HashMultiMap<>();
MultiMap<GroupKey2,MyObject> group2 = new HashMultiMap<>();

for (MyObject m : objectCollection)
{
    group1.put(new GroupKey1(m), m);
    group2.put(new GroupKey2(m), m);
}
...
// Retrieve the list of objects having a certain group-by key
GroupKey2 lookupKey = new Groupkey2(...);
Collection<MyObject> group = group2.get(lookupKey);
```

Comment: Of course, if the group by is a single field, you can likely just use the value type itself, e.g. `String`, `Integer`, `Date`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Taking your thoughts into account:

> What I want to do is divide objects into multiples sets based on some attributes in a very fast way. Basically like **SQL GROUP BY** statement but for Java.

```
Map<City, Set<String>> lastNamesByCity
     = people.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getCity,
                                          mapping(Person::getLastName, toSet())));
```